# Can I use Action.async with multiple Futures?

Tags: scala, playframework, future

In a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185074/my-playframework-action-returns-before-a-future-is-ready-how-do-i-update-a-web), I got advice on using Scala Futures with PlayFramework, thank you.  Now things have gotten a bit more complicated.  Let's say that before I just had to map where fruit could be found:

```
def getMapData(coll: MongoCollection[Document], s: String): Future[Seq[Document]] = ...

def mapFruit(collection: MongoCollection[Document]) = Action.async {
  val fut = getMapData(collection, "fruit")
  fut.map { docs: Seq[Document] =>
    Ok(docs.toJson)
  } recover {
    case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
  }
}
```

It turns out that people care more about Apples than Bananas or Cherries, so if no more than 100 items should appear on the map, people want Apples to have priority over Bananas and Cherries, but not more than some percentage of items on a map should be Apples.  Some function `pickDocs` determines the proper mix.  I thought something like this might just work, but no:

```
def mapApplesBananasCherries(collection: MongoCollection[Document]) = Action.async {
  val futA = getMapData(collection, "apples")
  val futB = getMapData(collection, "bananas")
  val futC = getMapData(collection, "cherries")
  futA.map { docsA: Seq[Document] =>
    futB.map { docsB: Seq[Document] =>
      futC.map { docsC: Seq[Document] =>
        val docsPicked = pickDocs(100, docsA, docsB, docsC)
        Ok(docsPicked.toJson)
      }
    }
    // won't compile without something here, e.g. Ok("whatever")
  } recover {
    case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
  }
}
```

Life was simple when I just had one Future, but now I have three.  What can I do to make this to (1) work and (2) again be simple?  I can't really construct a web response until all three Futures have values.

Comment: Is your problem only the compile error? If yes answers given below are all correct. If you want to bring the priorities into the play (say you don't want to get data for cherries or bananas if apples are already more than 100, or at least you don't want to wait until their result is ready) then you need a different approach (the answer given by @Luis Martinez is the best then)

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari Well first I wanted to understand why I couldn't just put the Ok() return in the innermost map, and you have all helped with that.  I'm very impressed with the quality of all the answers, now I just have to pick one approach.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't compile because your nested future block is returning a `Future[Future[Future[Response]]]`. If you instead use `flatMap` on the futures, Your futures will not be nested.

If you want this to be a little less repetitive, you can use `Future.sequence` instead to kick off futures simultaneously. You can either use pattern matching to re-extract the lists:

```
val futureCollections = List("apples", "bananas", "cherries").map{ getMapData(collection, _) }

Future.sequence(futureCollections) map { case docsA :: docsB :: docsC :: Nil =>
  Ok(pickDocs(100, docsA, docsB, docsC).toJson)
} recover {
  case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
}
```

or you could just hand the `pickDocs` function a list of lists (sorted by priority) for it to pick from.

```
Future.sequence(futureCollections) map { docLists =>
  Ok(pickDocs(docLists, 100, 0.75f).toJson)
} recover {
  case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
}
```

This `pickDocs` implementation will take a percentage of the head of the list, unless there aren't enough documents in the full list, in which it takes more, then recursively apply the same percentage on the remaining slots lists.

---

```
def pickDocs[T](lists: List[List[T]], max: Int, dampPercentage: Float): List[T] = {
  lists match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: tail =>
      val remainingLength = tail.flatten.length
      val x = max - remainingLength
      val y = math.ceil(max * dampPercentage).toInt
      val fromHere = head.take(x max y)
      fromHere ++ pickDocs(tail, max - fromHere.length, dampPercentage)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  (All these answers were great.)  I picked this one because it not only fixed the problem, but it also explained clearly the type of the return value of the nested future block, it re/taught me I need to think of using flatMap more often and why (as did most of the other answers), and it taught me about Future.sequence, about which I knew nothing before seeing this answer.  Then the answer went above and beyond with a possible implementation of pickDocs, which I will certainly mine for ideas.  My reaction to seeing this answer was basically:  Wow!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should use flatMap

```
futA.flatMap { docsA: Seq[String] =>
  futB.flatMap { docsB: Seq[String] =>
    futC.map { docsC: Seq[String] =>
      docsPicked = pickDocs(100, docsA, docsB, docsC)
        Ok(docsPicked.toJson)
      }
    }
}
```

Also, you can use for comprehension:

```
val res = for {
  docsA <- futA
  docsB <- futB
  docsC <- futC
} yield Ok(pickDocs(100, docsA, docsB, docsC).toJson)
res.recover {
  case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
}
```

Comment: I think he's referring to paralellized the future computations, even using a for comprehension it won't yield not until futc has completed

Comment: `val futA = getMapData(collection, "apples"); val futB = getMapData(collection, "bananas"); val futC = getMapData(collection, "cherries")` creates those futures, so the parallel computation is already started, a for comprehension just flatMaps over the results of these futures

Comment: Thank you Igor, this is very clear.  And thank you Luis and Nader!

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is that you want to execute apples, cherries and bananas in that priority, I would code it similar to this

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object WaitingFutures extends App {

  implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val apples = Future {50 + Random.nextInt(100)}
  val cherries = Future {50 + Random.nextInt(100)}
  val bananas =  Future {50 + Random.nextInt(100)}

  val mix = for {
    app <- apples
    cher <- if (app < 100) cherries else Future {0}
    ban <- if (app + cher < 100) bananas else Future {0}
  } yield (app,cher,ban)


  mix.onComplete {m =>
    println(s"mix ${m.get}")
  }

  Await.result(mix, 3 seconds)

}
```

if apples returns more than 100 when the future completes, it doesn't wait until cherries or bananas are done, but returns a dummy future with 0. If it's not enough it will wait until cherries are executed and so on.

NB I didn't put much effort on how to signal the if, so I'm using the dummy future which might not be the best approach.

Comment: OP problem might be just the compile error but this answer gives the best performance in terms of response time, but in some cases the calls to get bananas and cherries might be a waste of resource (it really depends on the frequency of the cases, i.e. how frequent it's the case that apples are more than 100)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common pattern for Futures and similar classes that "contain values" (e.g. `Option`, `List`)

To combine the results you want to use the [`flatMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S](f:T=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) method and the resulting code is

```
def mapApplesBananasCherries(collection: MongoCollection[Document]) = Action.async {
  val futA = getMapData(collection, "apples")
  val futB = getMapData(collection, "bananas")
  val futC = getMapData(collection, "cherries")
  futA.flatMap { docsA =>
    futB.flatMap { docsB =>
      futC.map { docsC =>
        val docsPicked = pickDocs(100, docsA, docsB, docsC)
        Ok(docsPicked.toJson)
      }
    }
  } recover {
    case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
  }
}
```

In fact it's so common that a special syntax exists to make it more readable, called *for-comprehension*: the following code is equivalent to the previous snippet

```
def mapApplesBananasCherries(collection: MongoCollection[Document]) = Action.async {
  val futA = getMapData(collection, "apples")
  val futB = getMapData(collection, "bananas")
  val futC = getMapData(collection, "cherries")
  for {
    apples <- futA
    bananas <- futB
    cherries <- futC
  } yield {
    val docsPicked = pickDocs(100, apples, bananas, cherries)
    Ok(docsPicked.toJson)
  } recover {
    case e => Console.err.println("FAIL: " + e.getMessage); BadRequest("FAIL")
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite equivalent: in the first snippet the futures are concurrent, in the second they aren't.

Comment: danielnixon you're right, later I'm gonna correct the answer